# SAAJInInterceptor and WSS4JInInterceptor CXF Interceptors

Tags: java, spring, web-services, cxf

Can any one please explain the difference between the 2 **cxf Interceptors** used in this bean configuration file.

Here i'm declaring an **jaxws:endpoint** element with the interceptors **SAAJInInterceptor** and **WSS4JInInterceptor**.

**Why 2 interceptors ?**

**What's the difference between the 2 ?**

**Can one interceptor work without the other ?**

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
        xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws 
                            http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs 
                            http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">
        <jaxws:endpoint id="auth"
                        implementor="com.company.auth.service.AuthServiceImpl" 
                        address="/corporateAuth">
            <jaxws:inInterceptors>
                <bean class="org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor"></bean>
                <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <map>
                            <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken" />
                            <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText" />
                            <entry key="passwordCallbackClass" value="com.company.auth.service.ServerPasswordCallback"></entry>
                        </map>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </jaxws:inInterceptors>
        </jaxws:endpoint>
    </beans>
```

Thank you for your explanations.

Answer (score 2):

The SAAJInterceptors only need to be added if you are using CXF 2.0.x or lower. From CXF 2.1.x they will be added automatically: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html

Comment: Hi @Colm, You know how I can send the name of the certificate with which I want to encrypt a response, whenever I make a request to the service, using Wss4jSecurityInterceptor?

Answer (score 1):

SAAJInInterceptor will transform the incoming message to a DOM message so that it can be processed by WSS4JInInterceptor. WSS4JInInterceptor applies the specified WS-Security actions on the incoming message.

Comment: can you give some explanation about the DOM Message.